# OnPostExecute is skipped

Tags: java, android

When I call an Async class with `new GiveMeJson2.execute(ref_id).get()`,

my app goes into `doInBackground`, creates a JSON string and returns it.

At this point, I think that the app has to go into `onPostExecute` and parse that JSON.

```
public class LiveArrivalActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ListViewLiveArrival adapter;
ListView listView;
public static ArrayList<LiveArrivalHelper> list = new ArrayList<LiveArrivalHelper>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_live_arrival);

    listView = findViewById(R.id.listView);

    FloatingActionButton fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Snackbar.make(view, "Replace with your own action", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                    .setAction("Action", null).show();
        }
    });

    Bundle b = getIntent().getExtras();
    Station station = (Station) b.get("Station");
    String ref_id = station.getRef_id();
    try {
        new GiveMeJson2().execute(ref_id).get();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ExecutionException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    Log.i("OUT", list.toString());

    adapter = new ListViewLiveArrival(this, list);
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
}    }

class GiveMeJson2 extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
String jsonText = "";
@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... stations) {

    try {
        URL url = new URL("https://www.trola.si/" + stations[0]);
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpURLConnection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");
        InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
        jsonText = readAll(bufferedReader);
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return jsonText;
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String s) {
    super.onPostExecute(s);
    try {
        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONObject(s).getJSONArray("stations");
        JSONArray buses = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0).getJSONArray("buses");
        for (int i = 0; i < buses.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = buses.getJSONObject(i);
            String direction = jsonObject.getString("direction");
            String number = jsonObject.getString("number");
            JSONArray arrivalsArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("arrivals");


            if (arrivalsArray.length() > 0){
                String arrivals = "";
                for (int j = 0; j < arrivalsArray.length(); j++) {
                    arrivals += arrivalsArray.get(j) + " min ";
                }
                Log.i("OUT", number+direction+arrivals.toString());
                LiveArrivalHelper liveArrivalHelper = new LiveArrivalHelper(direction,number,arrivals);
                LiveArrivalActivity.list.add(liveArrivalHelper);
            }
        }

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
} }
```

Any suggestions on why it's doing that?

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't? Try putting a log message in the first line of the onPostExecute()

Comment: I tried that. I also tried to place a breakpoint in it and debug it. It goes into doInBackground, but not in OnPostExecute

Comment: That's odd. Try overriding the onCancelled() method and putting a log in there. Maybe it's getting cancelled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you call `.get()` on an `AsyncTask`, it forces it to be called synchronous. Which in this case is on the Main Thread.

That's not allowed.
So the AsyncTask enters doInBackground, then the Android system immediately throws an error.

If you look in your LogCat, the error will be printed there.

You need to remove .get() from your AsyncTask and actually handle it async.

Comment: Ok, I removed it but I still get the same error. How exactly do I need to handle this?

Comment: `I still get the same error.` ??? You never told that you got an error.

Comment: I mean it's not an error realy, when I try to set adapter to listview with the list it return's an error because the list is empty. And it's empty because I can't figure out how to get data from api, because onPostExecute doesn't do it.

Comment: You should create and set the adapter in onPostExecute too.

Answer (score 0):

When you call an AsyncTask class with .get() like new GiveMeJson2.execute(ref_id).get() than indeed onPreExecute and onPostExecute are not called.